# Why isn't the template property displaying in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, frontend, vuejs3

Here's just the main.js file

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const counter = {
    // state
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0
        };
    },
    // view
    template: `
      <div>HI</div>
    `,
};

createApp(counter).mount('#app');
```

I don't see the template, I also have 'count' in vue devtools. public/index.html also has an id="app". And ESling don't say anything as well. I see just the clear page.

I expected to see 'HI' on the main page, or to see the div element in devtools. But i don't see anything. I think the template property doesn't display for some reason.

**package.json**

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: Your code works fine in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hodgkin-hp587c?file=/src/main.js).  Add your package.json to the question to show what packages and versions you've installed.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },

Comment: It's very strange that it works in a sandbox, but doesn't work in my project. I worked with vue before and I didn't have any problems with it. I created about 3 projects for solving this problem, but all of them don't work, I just see the clear page in browser, and don't see "<div>HI</div>" in DOM (only div#app)

Comment: I added your package.json info to your question where it is much more readable

Comment: try `import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';`

Comment: Thank you for editing my question (I'm new here and I don't know all the features yet). import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler' hellped me. It works, but why???
I'll be really grateful to you if you explain it to me or navigate me to other resources when I'll be able to read about it. Thank you very much!